# Including ASCII art in R

Tags: r, ascii-art

I'm writing a small program and wanted to know if there is a way to include ASCII art in R. I was looking for an equivalent of three quotes (`"""` or `'''`) in python.

I tried using `cat` or `print` with no success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately R can only represent literal strings by using single quotes or double quotes and that makes representing ascii art awkward; however, you can do the following to get a text representation of your art which can be output using R's `cat` function.

**1)** First put your art in a text file:

```
# ascii_art.txt is our text file with the ascii art
# For test purposes we use the output of say("Hello") from cowsay package 
# and put that in ascii_art.txt
library(cowsay)
writeLines(capture.output(say("Hello"), type = "message"), con = "ascii_art.txt")
```

**2)** Then read the file in and use `dput`:

```
art <- readLines("ascii_art.txt")
dput(art)
```

which gives this output:

```
c("", " -------------- ", "Hello ", " --------------", "    \\", 
"      \\", "        \\", "            |\\___/|", "          ==) ^Y^ (==", 
"            \\  ^  /", "             )=*=(", "            /     \\", 
"            |     |", "           /| | | |\\", "           \\| | |_|/\\", 
"      jgs  //_// ___/", "               \\_)", "  ")
```

**3)** Finally in your code write:

```
art <- # copy the output of `dput` here
```

so your code would contain this:

```
art <-
c("", " -------------- ", "Hello ", " --------------", "    \\", 
"      \\", "        \\", "            |\\___/|", "          ==) ^Y^ (==", 
"            \\  ^  /", "             )=*=(", "            /     \\", 
"            |     |", "           /| | | |\\", "           \\| | |_|/\\", 
"      jgs  //_// ___/", "               \\_)", "  ")
```

**4)** Now if we simply `cat` the `art` variable it shows up:

```
> cat(art, sep = "\n")

 -------------- 
Hello 
 --------------
    \
      \
        \
            |\___/|
          ==) ^Y^ (==
            \  ^  /
             )=*=(
            /     \
            |     |
           /| | | |\
           \| | |_|/\
      jgs  //_// ___/
               \_)
```

### Added

This is an addition several years later. In R 4.0 there is a new syntax that makes this even easier.  See `?Quotes`

> ```
>  Raw character constants are also available using a syntax similar
>  to the one used in C++: ‘r"(...)"’ with ‘...’ any character
>  sequence, except that it must not contain the closing sequence
>  ‘)"’. The delimiter pairs ‘[]’ and ‘{}’ can also be used, and ‘R’
>  can be used in place of ‘r’. For additional flexibility, a number
>  of dashes can be placed between the opening quote and the opening
>  delimiter, as long as the same number of dashes appear between the
>  closing delimiter and the closing quote.
> ```

For example:

```
hello <- r"{

 -------------- 
 Hello 
 --------------
    \
      \
        \
            |\___/|
          ==) ^Y^ (==
            \  ^  /
             )=*=(
            /     \
            |     |
           /| | | |\
           \| | |_|/\
      jgs  //_// ___/
               \_)
  
}"
cat(hello)
```

giving:

```
 -------------- 
 Hello 
 --------------
    \
      \
        \
            |\___/|
          ==) ^Y^ (==
            \  ^  /
             )=*=(
            /     \
            |     |
           /| | | |\
           \| | |_|/\
      jgs  //_// ___/
               \_)
```

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach: Use an API

URL - [artii](http://artii.herokuapp.com/)

Steps:

1. Fetch the data `ascii_request <- httr::GET("http://artii.herokuapp.com/make?text=this_is_your_text&font=ascii___")`
2. Retrieve the response - `ascii_response <- httr::content(ascii_request,as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")`
3. cat it out - `cat(ascii_response)`

If not connected to the web, you can set up your own server. [Read more here](https://github.com/potomak/artii-api)

Thanks to [@johnnyaboh](https://twitter.com/johnnyaboh) for setting up this amazing service

Answer (score 0):

Try the cat function, something like this should work:

```
cat(" \"\"\" ")
```

Comment: I don't get it. This will only print three quotes. Where do I insert the art?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I follow your question in that case. You were asking for "an equivalent of three quotes (""" or ''') in python". Could you please clarify?

Comment: In python you can use three quotes to create strings across multiple lines that let you output ascii art: http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Alpha&t=test. Strings literals:https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals